# Why is the projection tensor defined the following way?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

In Spacetime and Geometry, Carroll(2019) and more generally in physics the projection tensor/operator for a hypersurface $\Sigma$ is defined by
$$P_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu} - \sigma n_{\mu} n_{\nu},$$
where $\sigma=n_{\mu}n^{\mu}$. I want to understand why is the projection tensor defined this way, both from a mathematical and physics perspective.

Also, can anyhting be said about this expression $P^{ab}\nabla_{a}m_b$, where $P^{ab}$ is the projection operator and $m_b$ is the null normal to a surface.

Answer (score 2):

A projection operator satisfies two properties
$$
1)~P^2 = P, \qquad 2) ~ P \cdot n = 0
$$
where $n$ is normal to the subspace that $P$ projects to. Alternatively the second condition can also be written as
$$
2') ~ P \cdot t = t
$$
where $t$ is any vector that lives entirely in the subspace that $P$ projects to. In other words, $t \cdot n = 0$.

You can check that your projection tensor satisfies all these properties.